# Are there any plans to add Hardware Wallet support to the core Monero software?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, hardware-wallet

Hardware wallets are good for securing your coins, but when they are made, will core devs add support to the core Monero wallet software? Or will this type of thing not be supported by core software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ledger Wallet is currently working on a hardware wallet. The subreddit /r/monero links to it in the side bar, and the github page LedgerHQ/blue-app-monero has some of the code that will make it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends in large part on what kind of changes would be required. That said, as a first approximation, adding support would seem like a good thing. If the driver program ends up totally separate, it can be a different binary too.

No current plans though. Plans can only be made when we know what the hardware is, what it needs in order to work with the host computer, etc.